# Changing the value of a variable in a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

so I'm learning about threads, and I can't seem to get a program working with Threads.

Basic code is:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CLASS1 extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
public CLASS2 class2Variable1 = new CLASS2();
public CLASS2 class2Variable2 = new CLASS2();
public Thread thread1 = new Thread(class2Variable1);
public Thread thread2 = new Thread(class2Variable2);

public CLASS1()
{
    //Not Important for example
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CLASS1 class1 = new CLASS1();
    class1.createAndShowGUI();
}

public void createAndShowGUI()
{
    CLASS1 frame = new CLASS1();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,200));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.addKeyListener(frame);
    frame.add(class2Variable1);
    frame.add(class2Variable2);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    class2Variable1.speed = class2Variable1.speed + 10;
    class2Variable1.changeText("CHANGED VALUE TO: " + class2Variable1.speed);
    //Also Tried class2Variable1.labelText.setText("CHANGED VALUE");
    class2Variable1.revalidate();
    class2Variable1.repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
}
}

class CLASS2 extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
public int speed = 0;
public JLabel labelText = new JLabel(); //Also tried Initializing it here

public void changeText(String text)
{
    labelText.setText(text);
    labelText.repaint();
}

public void run()
{
    addStuff();
}

public CLASS2()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout());
}

public void addStuff()
{
    labelText.setText("INITIAL VALUE");
    add(labelText);
    }
}
```

All the KeyEvents work, but if I check the variable var1 with a messageDialog, it shows me the value at the initialization (0), not the value of the thread(100). I also can't change the text in the JLabel, even with setText.

Comment: Where is this messageDialog? This is important to the question. It's probably just a race condition

Comment: Hmm, of course you don't get the new value, because you set the var1 variable, no jlable text, also after each set(`setText()`) you would call the `repaint()` method to force the component to repaint out.

Comment: The messageDialog is run from the method that changes var1's value.

Comment: The JLabel actually does have some Text in it, I just didn't think it would make any difference in the example. I've also tried called repaint() and revalidate() after each setText(), including in the first class, as well as using methods to set it in the second class and calling repaint() from that method

Comment: I call the messageDialog in Class1, I.e. class2var1.var1 = 20

Comment: If your problem isn't solved yet, provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), because right now I can't reproduce the problem (your example code doesn't even compile)

Comment: I edited my original post to include a better SSCCE, which should compile, as I tested it on my machine and it compiled, and should be a correct representation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the variable `var1` will not change the label's text. You have to call `varLabel.setText` with the changed value.

Also read this article about threading with swing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

The solution should look like this:

```
public void run()
{
     var1 = 100;
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            varLabel.setText(String.valueOf(var1));
            // varLabel.repaint(); // might be necessary?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "I also can't change the text in the JLabel, even with setText."

Comment: I need to be able to change the value of var1 multiple times, So that wouldn't work would it? I.e. If I called class2var1.varLabel.setText("TEXT"); then class2var1.varLabel.setText("OTHER TEXT"); It wouldn't change wouldn't it, as in it would just change it when the thread is started and that's it

Comment: `setText` will change the text whenever you call it. Just remember to wrap it in a runnable as shown above when you are not in the UI thread.

Comment: As I've already said, setText isn't working, no matter where I call it from, or if I call repaint(), the Label refuses to change